# Small c++ game using graphics.h , calling multiple functions at once ? (multi threading?)

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, bgi

I'm writing a small ball game. I have a function called `gravity` and I also have a while loop that checks whether the user wants to move the ball using wsad keys.

Do I need to multi thread this or is there another way out? I cut out some of the irrelevant code for setting up the program. Here is just the stuff that matters:

```
while(1) {
enableGravity();
char ch = getch();// i know getch() is not going to cut it
//maybe 2 different f() multi threaded , for gravity and position, 
f(ch == 'w' || ch == 'W')
                updateObjPosition('U');       
          else if(ch == 's' || ch == 'S')
                updateObjPosition('D');
          else if(ch == 'a' || ch == 'A')
                updateObjPosition('L');
          else  if(ch == 'd' || ch == 'D')
                updateObjPosition('R');

          }
```

I have these functions in main. I need the program to enable gravity and also be able to accept input to move the ball through `updateObjPosition()` **simultaneously**.

Comment: You are probably looking for [kbhit](http://www.cprogramming.com/fod/kbhit.html) function.

Comment: You probably don't want to make a "small game" multithreaded.  It's hard.

Answer (score 4):

You *could* use multiple threads. A more obvious possibility would be a non-blocking keyboard read.

If you're doing this on Windows, you probably have a `_kbhit` in your standard library that will tell you if a key on the keyboard has been pressed. If you're using curses, you can use `nodelay` to tell getch to return immediately, whether a key has been pressed or not. Other systems may do things in different ways still, but you get the general idea...

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to multi-thread. You just need an API that returns TRUE if a specified key is currently pressed down. That will likely be platform dependent. What platform are you building/running on?

For example on Win32: [GetAsyncKeyState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646293%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: windows , but the program compiled is a console type application(sorry im a newbie in c++)

Comment: Jesus has nothing to do with this... on Windows it's `_kbhit`, so it's still platform dependent.

Comment: @DanielEarwicker he is using TC 3.1,  windows.h didnt existed during that time ? i think! , Even i agree GetAsyncKeyState is 100 times better then _kbhit solution :P

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned you are using old Borland compiler on TC 3.1 in the old conio.h there was a function

```
   kbhit();
```

the function was a one shot solution for getting if any key is pressed on the keyboard 
so here is your loop to get key input

```
  int getKey(){
     if(kbhit){
        return getch();
     }
     return -1;
 }
```

By they way you should upgrade to VC 08 Atleast!

For your simple project where the logic loop i guess will be quite small this will handle all the pain for you but if you write a longer application with hard logic then you will have to use better and Asynchronous methods for IO and those methods basically involve working on 2 threads 1 getting Input and the other doing logic operations ..